# numpy array of list to 2d array

Tags: numpy

```
>>> print(a)
 
array([list([52, 584, 78]), list([35, 140, 584])], dtype=object)
```

I would like to convert above data to numpy 2d array with int, but when I enter np.array(a), the result was the same as before. How can I convert type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use np.stack

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = ([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = ([2,3,4,5,6])
>>> c = ([3,4,5,6,7])

>>> np.array([a, b, c])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])

>>> np.stack([a, b, c], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: Your use of `np.array` created the 2d array the OP wanted.  Reproducing the original object dtype array is a bit trickier.  But you are right about using `np.stack`